# How will astronauts live in Spacex's red dragon?

Tags: spacex, crewed-spaceflight, deep-space, red-dragon

If SpaceX's Red Dragon will ever bring astronauts to the red planet, would it need to connect to a deep space habitat? I'm asking because the red dragon seems to be too small for a seven or eight month trip to Mars.

Comment: I think this is a reasonable question, not sure why it was down voted. Not everyone follows individual companies' future plans carefully. I think I've read somewhere that the first Red Dragon to land on Mars would have windows - and so I imagined it would have seats for PR reasons - live videos shot from the interior, looking out — something to stir the imaginations of people like this guy https://youtu.be/QmSJlgI04PA

Comment: @uhoh some visual information for M, Tyler - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0qo78R_yYFA - a Link to SpaceX's method of getting to Mars. The ship depicted is not a Red Dragon.  I don't down vote ... I see the question as being interestingly enough, the very criticism of the Orion Capsule approach originally leading up to the more updated approach of adding a Habitat. So if nothing else hopefully the Linked Video shows two very different approaches. SpaceX will carry "100 and perhaps as many as 200 people" at a time. http://www.space.com/34210-elon-musk-unveils-spacex-mars-colony-ship.html

Comment: With the intent to stay but as Elon says, the Ship is coming back so anyone that wants to return may do so

Comment: I downvoted due to the lack of prior research that was shown; some basic Googling would've shown that Red Dragon's uncrewed.

Comment: @DylanSp for a very new user it can be helpful to take a moment and leave a short explanation, or even a suggestion how to improve the question. I remember when I was just starting out in stackexchange and stackoverflow the unexplained, silent down votes were horribly demoralizing. Just a thought.

Answer (score 10):

They won't. Red Dragon is an unmanned concept demonstrator and experiment transport. SpaceX wants to use it to test Mars EDL (entry-descent-landing) technology and algorithms they develop for their next generation ship (currently known as [ITS or BFR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ITS_launch_vehicle)) which they want to use for astronauts.

Comment: Some info about possible payloads for example [here](http://space.stackexchange.com/q/15025/10829)